# Why creating thread in constructor results in runtime error

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have following code in C++, I am trying to spawn new thread from the constructor of a class. I get run time error. I do not understand why, and how could it be prevented. I am quite newbie in C++. In VS2017, it errors in abort() has been called.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class Rectangle {
public:
    int area(void);
    Rectangle();
    ~Rectangle();

private:
    int x, y;
    int UpdateData();
};

Rectangle::Rectangle() {
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
    std::thread modelThread(&Rectangle::UpdateData, this);
}

Rectangle::~Rectangle() {
}
int Rectangle::area() {
    return x * y;
}
int Rectangle::UpdateData()
{
    while (true) {
        x++;
        y += 2;
        std::cout << "Area with x:" << x << " y:" << y << " area:" << Rectangle::area() << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    Rectangle rect;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `modelThread` object is destroyed while the thread is still running. [This causes `terminate` to be called](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread). You need to make sure the `thread` object outlives the thread (usually by calling `join()` on it), or else `detach()` the thread.

Comment: Thanks. I understood why it was generating error. I added modelThread.join(). The run-time error is now gone. But now, I cannot execute the code in main function. How can I achieve both.

Comment: It does not make sense to use a thread in you example as you have nothing else to do while waiting. And there are no exit condition so your program would run forever and eventually computed area will overflow (and then y, then x). Also as you have no synchronization in your code, you would not be able to safely use data from other threads anyway. Better to learn multithreading first by reading good books like **C++ Concurrency in Action** and once you have minimal understand of how it works, try to write some code. You cannot improvise multithreaded code!

Comment: Obviously, if your `modelThread` is inside `Rectangle` constructor, you cannot wait on it from main. Thus the threading object should be declared in `main`... but without proper exist condition, you would wait infinitely anyhow. In your case, it is probably easier to use `std::async` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`main` and `modelThread` are threads but `modelThread` is launched from `main` via the constructor of `Rectangle`. However, when main ends,  `rect` goes out of scope and is destroyed, while the thread launched in its constructor is still running. This causes the run-time error.
So you have to join the `modelThread` to the `main` thread to ensure that the main waits until the `modelThread` has finished running.

> But now, I cannot execute the code in main function. How can I achieve both

For this you will have to make `UpdateData` `public` and start the `modelThread` in main like this:

```
std::thread modelThread(&Rectangle::UpdateData, &rect);
```

Even with `std::async` you will have to make `UpdateData` `public` and use it like this:

```
std::future<int> fut =  std::async (&Rectangle::UpdateData, &rect);
```

If you **do not want** to make `UpdateData` `public`, declare a `friend` function in Rectangle class (which can access all its private members and functions) and call `UpdateData` in the `friend` function and start a thread in `main` with that `friend` function.

```
std::future<int> fut =  std::async (&FriendFunc, &rect);
```

Then you will be able to execute code in `main` without waiting for `UpdateData` to finish. Then you can get the value computed by the `UpdateData` function using the following in `main`.

```
int ret = fut.get();
```

If you want the outputs from `main` and `UpdateData` not to be mixed up do this.
Declare a `private` member variable in `Rectangle`

```
std::mutex mtx; //uses <mutex>
```

And use it like this:

```
int Rectangle::UpdateData()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    while (true) {
        x++;
        y += 2;
        std::cout << "Area with x:" << x << " y:" << y << " area:" << Rectangle::area() << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried with std::thread modelThread(&Rectangle::UpdateData, &rect) after making UpdateData function public, the program compiles. But, UpdateData is not function working. I get output like this "Area with x:This is the main thread up and running2 y:
4 area:8Main thread ID:8376". So, Std::cout is used by both threads at once.

Comment: If cout is used by both threads, you will have to protect one using a mutex to avoid overlapping of output. Will update answer.

Comment: I tried with the mutex and locking as you mentioned, still the problem persists.

Comment: I tried it on my PC. It works.  The outputs from main and Update data are printed on different lines. Are you using line breaks in main also?

Comment: I added one each std::cout before and after thread creation. like this,  std::cout << "Number of threads = " << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << std::endl;
 Rectangle rect;
 std::cout << "Number of threads = " << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << std::endl;
 std::thread t(&Rectangle::UpdateData, &rect);
 std::cout << "Number of threads = " << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << std::endl;

Comment: If you have cout in multiple threads you will have to protect each of them with the same mutex. Then the mutex has to be global, not private.

Comment: The std::cout in previous comments are not in different threads,they are all in main thread except the thread t which runs the UpdateData.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179358/discussion-between-p-w-and-main).